# Append row entries of specific column to empty dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dictionary of dataframes called dictoftickersdf that looks like this.

I will cycle over each frame using a for loop in the dictionary. So assume each one is called tickersdf.

```
    Country Type  Ticker
1   US      Pub   AAPL
2   US      Priv  etc
3   GER     Pub   etc
4   HK      Pub   etc
```

and

```
    Country Type  Ticker
1   US      Pub   GE
2   US      Priv  etc
3   GER     Pub   etc
4   HK      Pub   etc
5   US      Pub   MSFT
```

```
etc..
```

I have an empty dataframe, `df = pd.DataFrame()`

I am running a for loop over various tickersdf which have different companies.

I want to only append the entries that appear in the column ticker based on certain conditions (Type == Pub and Country == US).

So I want the end df to look like this

```
AAPL
GE
MSFT
...
```

So far I have this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"/Users/xxx/Documents/"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print(filepath)

        dictoftickersdf = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name=None) #multiple sheets per file

        for key, tickersdf in dictoftickersdf.items():
            df = df.append(tickersdf.loc[(tickersdf['Country']=='US') & (tickersdf['Type']=='Pub'),'Ticker'])
```

But the dataframe df comes up empty, what am I doing wrong?

Update:

I added an assignment command at the end and its not empty anymore but it's still not working right. Now the df looks like this

```
          1     1     5    ...
Ticker    AAPL  NaN   NaN  ...
Ticker    NaN   GE    MSFT ...
Ticker    ....................
```

Comment: the issue with your code is that your not assigning the append to anything, your just calling it. also it will append via columns, so you'll end up with a column per dataframe.

Comment: how do I assign it then?

Comment: I did df = df.append(tickersdf.loc[(tickersdf['Country']=='US') & (tickersdf['Type']=='Pub'),'Ticker']) , now its kinda working, but the its appending sideways

Comment: I figured it out, I had to use pd.Series() instead of pd.DataFrame()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use pd.Series instead of pd.DataFrame because I was only getting a single series.

```
df = pd.Series()

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"/Users/xxx/Documents/"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print(filepath)

        dictoftickersdf = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name=None) #multiple sheets per file


        for key, tickersdf in dictoftickersdf.items():
            df = df.append(tickersdf.loc[(tickersdf['Country']=='US') & (tickersdf['Type']=='Pub'),'Ticker'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'Public' is shortened to just 'Pub' in your dataframe. Try shortening that part to see if that fixes it.

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my part, ill fix it